# IVP Using Numerical Methods

Tags: numerical-analysis

> Suppose that $y(t)$ is the exact solution of the ivp $$y'(t)=f(t,y(t)), y(0)=y_0$$ and $u(t)$ is any approximation to $y(t)$ with $u(0)=y(0)$. Define the error $e(t)=y(t)-u(t)$.

How can I show that $e(t)$ satisfies the ivp $$e'(t)=f(t,u(t)+e(t))-u'(t), e(0)=0$$ And if we say that $f(t,y)=\lambda y$ for some constant $\lambda$, how can we solve the ivp from my previous question to show that $u(t)+e(t)=y(t)$?

Comment: Two points. First, at least part of your problem about showing $e(t)$ satisfies the IVP is trivial.  You should at least spot which of the two parts is easier.  Second, the last part of the Question assumes $f(t,y) = \lambda y$.  This lack of dependence of $f$ on "time" $t$ is often referred to as an autonomous system.  Special deductions can be made from this property.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, notice that
\begin{align*}
e' &= (y-u)' 
\\
&= y' - u' 
\\
&= f(t,y) - u' \tag{1}.
\end{align*}
In equation (1) we can use $y=u+e$.  This gives
$$
e' = f(t,u+e)-u'.
$$

For the second question, if $y'=\lambda y$, then using separation of variables gives $y(t) = y_0 e^{\lambda t}$.  Since $f(t,y) =\lambda y$, the differential equation for $e$ takes the form
\begin{align*}
e' &=  f(t,u+e) - u'  
\\
&= \lambda (u+e)-u'.
\end{align*}
Put $e$ on the left hand side, and $u$ on the right hand side.  This gives
$$
e' -\lambda e = - (u'-\lambda u).
$$
Using the integrating factor $\mu(t) = \exp{(-\lambda t)}$, we obtain
$$
(\mu(t) e )' = - (\mu(t) u)'
\implies
\int (\mu(t) e )'\,dt =- \int (\mu(t) u)'\,dt.
$$
Hence, $\mu(t) e = -\mu(t) u +C$, where $C$ is a constant of integration.  Using the initial condition $e(0)=0$, one finds that $C=y_0$.  Solving for $e$ then gives
$$
e(t) = -u(t) + \frac{y_0}{\mu(t)}.
$$
Notice that $1/\mu(t) = \exp{( \lambda t)}$, so 
$$
e(t) = -u(t) + \frac{y_0}{\mu(t)}
=
-u(t) +y_0\exp{( \lambda t)}
=
-u(t)+y(t).
$$
Thus, $u(t)+e(t) =y(t)$.